# Can I pass day|month|year specific values through to a silex form datatype of date

Tags: twig, silex

Is there a way to pass the 'attr' and 'constraints' through so they apply to the day, month or year of a birthday/date object?

This is what I currently have but they are only getting applied to the overall div

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form')
    ->add(
        'registerDOB',
        'birthday',
        array(
            'widget' => 'text',
            'input' => 'string',
            'label' => 'Date of birth',
            'format' => 'ddMMyyyy',
            'error_bubbling' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'day' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-input form-register-postcode',
                    'data-required' => 'true',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'data-error-message' => ''
                )
            ),
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(
                    array(
                        'message' => 'DOB must not be blank.',
                    )
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
```

ouput when called via {{ form_widget(form.registerDOB) }}

```
<div data-error-message="" placeholder="" data-required="true" class="form-input form-register-postcode" id="form_registerDOB">
    <input type="text" required="required" name="form[registerDOB][day]" id="form_registerDOB_day" class="parsley-validated">
    <input type="text" required="required" name="form[registerDOB][month]" id="form_registerDOB_month" class="parsley-validated">
    <input type="text" required="required" name="form[registerDOB][year]" id="form_registerDOB_year" class="parsley-validated">
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to override the `date_widget` block for this.

Comment: That is the conclusion we had come to as well.  I was hoping I was missing something obvious :(